# Обход вложенной структуру JSON в AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

```
$scope.questions =
[
        {
            "id": 1, 
            "question": "Who are you?", 
                "answers": [
                            {
                                "id" : 1,
                                "answer":   "asd",
                                "isSelected" : 1
                            }, 
                            {   "id" : 2,
                                 "answer": "zxc",
                                 "isSelected" : 1
                            }, 
                            {    "id" : 3,
                                 "answer": "Мrty",
                                 "isSelected" : 1
                            }

                         ],
                "allowMultipleChoice" : true,
                "isEnabled" : true,
                "NowSelected" : 0
        },

        {
            "id": 2, 
            "question": "New question?", "answers": [
                                                                                                {
                                                                                                    "id" : 1,
                                                                                                    "answer": "Personal",
                                                                                                    "isSelected" : 0
                                                                                                }, 
                                                                                                {
                                                                                                    "id" : 2,
                                                                                                    "answer": "Goverment",
                                                                                                    "isSelected" : 0
                                                                                                }
                                                                                              ],
            "allowMultipleChoice" : true,
            "isEnabled" : true,
            "NowSelected" : 0
        },

        {
            "id": 3, "question": "What is your name?", "answers": [
                                                                    {"id": 1, "answer" : "Dima", "isSelected" : 0}, 
                                                                    {"id": 2, "answer": "Roma", "isSelected" : 0}, 
                                                                    {"id": 3, "answer": "Masha", "isSelected" : 0}],
            "allowMultipleChoice" : false,
            "isEnabled" : true,
            "NowSelected" : 0
        },
        {
            "id": 4, "question": "Where do you live?", "answers": ["Moscow", "London", "Minsk"],
            "isEnabled" : true,
            "NowSelected" : 0
        }
]
```

Мне нужно добраться до вложенного элемента `isSelected` и поменять его значение. Что-то делаю не так во вложенном цикле. Подскажите в чем ошибка

```
        angular.forEach($scope.questions, function(question)
        {
            console.log(question);
            angular.forEach(question.answers, function(val))
            {
                //question.answers или что должно быть?
            }
        }

            )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во второй `forEach` неправильно закрыли скобки. Так лучше:

```
angular.forEach($scope.questions, function (question) {
    angular.forEach(question.answers, function (answer) {
        console.log(answer.isSelected);
    });
});
```